# Getting class name from Abstract class in a static property

Tags: java

I have this class and I want to know if it is possible to get the name of the class in a statuc way

```
public abstract class AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler<T extends AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedEvent> extends DaCommonEventHandler<T> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger ( this.getClass());
```

Comment: `AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler.class.getName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just 'hardcode' this class name? It's common approach when it comes to loggers

```
public abstract class AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler<T extends AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedEvent> extends DaCommonEventHandler<T> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler.class);
    ...
}
```

every other solution is to be honest overkill for this

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler.class);
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation about what the problem is and how this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler<T extends AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedEvent> extends DaCommonEventHandler<T> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger ( AbstractDAProcedureMenuReceivedHandler.class);
```